# How can I force a WordPress Query to satisfy ALL requirements?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have 2 categories, called `red` and `blue`. 
I have 2 posts, called `red-post` and `blue-post`. These posts are of their corresponding categories.

If I create the following query:

```
$bluePostQuery = new WP_Query(array('category' => 'red', 'name' => 'blue-post'));
```

This query **will** return `blue-post`, even though my query has category=red as a requirement. Why does this happen? `blue-post` is of the category blue, not red, so I want nothing returned here. Will a query always return if the `name` argument is provided, even if the other arguments are not met?

Answer (score 1):

It may be ignoring 'category' because that is not a valid parameter for finding a category in WP Query.  [Here's a list of the valid params for cats](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters).  You might try using the category name parameter, like so:

```
$bluePostQuery = new WP_Query(
      array(
       'category_name' => 'red', 
       'name' => 'blue-post'
       )
);
```

Alternatively, if you are searcing for a specific post, and know its slug, the category doesn't really matter, so you could just exclude it.